# In Redactor backspace button erase the formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

Hi I am working on the Redactor editor in the jquery, I make the formatting for the text It shows properly but problem is that when I pressed the backspace button then the formatting get vanished and the text shows as a normal text. How to fix the issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

solution for the above problem is that just find out the keyCode for the BACKSPACE and the DELETE button (in Redactor.min.js file )and just remove the code from the condition that removes the formatting in the js.It does not affect on the erase and the delete functionality...! Thank you.

Comment: worked for me , just commented out:  // BACKSPACE: 8,
 // DELETE: 46 from redactor.js